# Reset Vuetify form validation

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I have trouble resetting vuetify validation in v-dialog.

This codepen is the simplified version of what I have.
https://codepen.io/yuukive/pen/BVqpEZ

With the code above, if I do

(Open dialog --> press SAVE button --> (validation fails) --> press CLOSE button --> open dialog again),

it is already validated when I open the dialog again...

Is it possible to reset validation before a user opens it the 2nd time?

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: () => ({
    dialog: false,
    emailRules: [v => !!v || 'Name is required']
  }),
  methods: {
    onSave() {
      if (!this.$refs.form.validate()) return
      dialog = false
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-layout row justify-center>
      <v-dialog v-model="dialog" persistent max-width="500px">
        <v-btn slot="activator" color="primary" dark>Open Dialog</v-btn>
        <v-card>
          <v-card-title>
            <span class="headline">Email</span>
          </v-card-title>
          <v-form ref="form">
            <v-card-text>
              <v-container grid-list-md>
                <v-layout wrap>
                  <v-flex xs12>
                    <v-text-field label="Email" required :rules="emailRules"></v-text-field>
                  </v-flex>
                </v-layout>
              </v-container>
              <small>*indicates required field</small>
            </v-card-text>
            <v-card-actions>
              <v-spacer></v-spacer>
              <v-btn color="blue darken-1" flat @click.native="dialog = false">Close</v-btn>
              <v-btn color="blue darken-1" flat @click.native="onSave">Save</v-btn>
            </v-card-actions>
          </v-form>
        </v-card>
      </v-dialog>
    </v-layout>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Answer (score 59, accepted):

[Example](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/forms#example-validation-with-submit-and-clear) from docs uses:

`this.$refs.form.reset()`

Note that while `reset()` clears validation, it clears input as well.
You can follow [this issue](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/3316) to see further updates on this.

So you can perhaps watch dialog value and reset the form:

```
watch: {
    dialog() {
        this.$refs.form.reset()
    }
}
```

Comment: if I have another form as I could use reboot or validate, example: this.$refs.formNew.reset()

Answer (score 41):

`resetValidation()` will clear validation errors only, `reset()` will also clear input fields.

Answer (score 4):

`this.$refs.form.reset()` might work on `JavaScript`, but compiler for `TypeScript` complains about typing. Even though during `serve` you can only see errors in the terminal without breaking the app, it'll actually break when you'll try to `build` the app.

Creating a new variable and assigning into it `any` type does the trick, below an example:

```
const refForm: any = this.$refs.form;
refForm.reset();
```

Comment: I believe this will also do what you want:  `(this.$refs.form as HTMLFormElement).resetValidation()`